# Accessing Materialize chip response to Ruby Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Materialize CSS Chips to store the tag for my video whose html goes like:

```
<%=simple_form_for @video do |form| %>
 <div id="spaceTags" class="chips chips-placeholder">
 <div>
<% end %>
```

and the JavaScript Intialization Goes like:

```
$('.chips').material_chip();
$('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
});
```

and my Controller Goes like:

```
 @video = Video.new(video_params)
@video.uploader = current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @video.save
    format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

How can I retrieve the data and get access to it in my controller?

Comment: Not familiar with material_chip but probably it's adding data in the front end.  Only way to get it back to rails server is via some ajax post/put request.  You'll need to write JS to send that.  Controller knows nothing of the front end as it lives on the server in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The Materialize CSS library triggers events whenever a chip is added/deleted/selected. You can trigger AJAX calls to let your Rails controller know what happened on the client.

Or, you could wait for all interactions to happen and let the user trigger the AJAX request through a button click in one shot.

You can learn more about chip features here:

[Materialize CSS Chips Documentation](http://materializecss.com/chips.html)

```js
 $('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
    // you have the added chip here
    //Call AJAX to talk to Rails Controller
  });

  $('.chips').on('chip.delete', function(e, chip){
    // you have the deleted chip here
    //Call AJAX to talk to Rails Controller
  });

  $('.chips').on('chip.select', function(e, chip){
    // you have the selected chip here
    //Call AJAX to talk to Rails Controller
  });
```

Comment: When i try it calling through the AJAX the other form data is send separately and the AJAX data is send separately leading to the executing the same code two times but with the incomplete data as both of them should execute same code together.

Comment: You can use the callbacks to update a hidden form element on the other form so that they get posted together as one request. You can basically use the changed values from the callback and use it as you see fit. You could even store it in a scoped variable and use it when making the AJAX requests.